# Работа с Predicate

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть задача, нужно сделать фильтры для стримов с разными типами объектов.

Была идея сделать что-то типо такого:

```
private static <T> Predicate<? super CategoryStatisticsDto> byDateTo(Date dateTo) {
    return t -> t.getPurchaseDate() != null && dateTo.after(t.getPurchaseDate());
}

private static <T> Predicate<? super Basket> byDateTo(Date dateTo) {
    return t -> t.getPurchaseDate() != null && dateTo.after(t.getPurchaseDate());
}
```

то есть делать фильтр а предикат бы выбирался исходя из того какой тип объекта в стриме

```
stream = stream.filter((Predicate<? super T>) byDateTo(searchParams.getDateTo()));
```

но что-то пошло не так, а точнее фильтры имеют одинаковую сигнатуру и следовательно не могут быть скомпилированы :)

```
method <T>byDateTo(Date) is already defined in class SearchUtil
where T is a type-variable:
T extends Object declared in method <T>byDateTo(Date)
```

Хотя для одного типа объектов всё компилируется и классно работает

Comment: что именно "что-то пошло не так" ?

Comment: @AndrewBystrov, извиняюсь, добавил в описание

Comment: `следовательно не могут быть скомпилированы` добавьте в вопрос текст ошибки компиляции

Comment: @gil9red добавил

Answer (score 0):

У вас проблема в том, что после [стирания типов](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html) у вас остается 2 метода, с одинаковыми названиями: `byDateTo`, а в java, как известно, нельзя создавать 2 метода с одинаковыми именами. Соответственно, чтобы решить, нужно либо называть методы по разному, либо создать метод обертку, который в зависимости от типа данных в `stream` будет выбирать нужный вам предикат

Comment: То есть мне всё же придется вручную чекать тип, а автоматически по красоте никак не сделать?